# Regex, extract e-mail from an HTML

Tags: html, regex

How can I extract e-mail, from this email:

```
Email <a href=""mailto:aampianos@aol.com"">aampianos@aol.com</a>
```

My Regex

```
(?<=Email)(.*)(?=<\/)
```

So far I was able to discard word Email and the 'a' closing tag (`</a>`) to this:

```
<a href=""mailto:aampianos@aol.com"">aampianos@aol.com
```

But how can I remove the 'a' opening tag along with href (`<a href=""mailto:aampianos@aol.com"">`) and only be left with the email?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2897426

Comment: Ah, another one trying to collect email address from web pages?

Comment: `<a href=""mailto:aampianos@aol.com"">` ... why **`""`**... **`""`** ? Is that the problem that is preventing you from using an HTML parser?

Comment: Just using VBA to collect some data of a website, can't use .innertext on every page due to poor html structure, hence had to resort to regex.

Comment: very simple (e.g. for validation): `/\S+@\S+\.\S+/`. works for your example: `/([\w-\.]+@[\w-\.]+\.\w+)/` (http://regexr.com/3ebl6)

Comment: Thanks Simon, not quite what I was looking for, but it will do. Want to post your answer, so I can approve it?

Comment: `(?<=mailto:)[^"]+` perhaps. https://regex101.com/r/eAwWQp/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if this helps but i wont do that with RegEx. would try to split after `mailto:` and search the next `"`. Everything between that COULD be an eMailadress.

Comment: The regular expression for this is: `(?<=mailto:)[^"]+` https://regex101.com/r/eAwWQp/1

Answer (score 0):

A real email regex is really complex, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2897426

A very simple email validation regex would be

```
/\S+@\S+\.\S+/
```

It doesn't work here because the email address is wrapped in text, so you can't use the `\S` for any non-whitespace character, but you can instead match `\w` (character, digit or underscore), `-` and `.` as "allowed" characters:

```
/([\w-\.]+@[\w-\.]+\.\w+)/
```

example: http://regexr.com/3ebl6

keep in mind that me@[127.0.0.1] would be a valid email address, too.